# angular ngFor how to get child length

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to do Check length of child in my *ngFor element. I read data from a firebase real-time database. where I am wrong?

this my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
   <div>Eventname:{{event.name}} </div>
   <div> Amount of Arrival: {{event.arrival.length}} </div>
</div>
```

this my DB:

```
 Event{
  a{
    date: "12,Nov"
    name: "best event"
    arrival:{
      a{
        name:"david",
        from:"USA"
       }
      b{
        name:"Mike",
        from:"GER"
       } 
    }
   }
}
```

this my service:

```
   getDataList(listpath:string){
    this.itemsRef = this.db.list(listpath);
    this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    );
  return this.items;
  }
```

this my component:

```
    this.db.getDataList("/Event/" ).subscribe(res => {
     this.events=res;
  });
```

Comment: can you see how the response is coming?try printing it to the console

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
{{Object.keys(event.arrival).length}}
```

Reference [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

event Arrival is now object, if you can change it to Array, then you can use length. {} - object, [] - array. Good luck!